# Heroku gives "Connection closed without response" error when trying to use https

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, https

I've created a single page app using the PERN stack and have successfully deployed it to Heroku. Now I am trying to switch to https on the backend, and have creaed a selfsigned.crt file and a selfsigned.key file, but I can't figure out this current error.

**Here's my db.js**

```
let connectionString = {
    connectionString:
        process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    ssl: true,
};

const pool = new Pool(connectionString);

module.exports = pool;
```

**Here's my server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const fs = require("fs");
const https = require("https");
const httpsPort = process.env.PORT || 8443;
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync("./sslCertification/selfsigned.key", "utf8");
const certificate = fs.readFileSync("./sslCertification/selfsigned.crt", "utf8");
const credentials = { key: privateKey, cert: certificate };

const priorityStatus = require("./routes/priorityStatus");
const accounts = require("./routes/accounts");
const projects = require("./routes/projects");
const bugs = require("./routes/bugs");
const comments = require("./routes/comments");

app.use(express.json());

app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] != 'https')
        res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url)
    else
        next()
});

// Needed since single page application
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use(express.static('client/build'));
}
app.get('*', (request, response) => {
    response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build', 'index.html'));
});

app.use("/api/priority-status", priorityStatus);
app.use("/api/account", accounts);
app.use("/api/project", projects);
app.use("/api/bug", bugs);
app.use("/api/comment", comments);

const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

httpsServer.listen(httpsPort);

// Was using this before switching to https
/* app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => {
    console.log("Server has started on port 5000");
}); */
```

---

**Here's what I get in my Heroku log --tail.**

```
2020-12-16T23:45:25.843470+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] > server@1.0.0 client /app  
2020-12-16T23:45:25.843471+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] > npm start --prefix ./client  
2020-12-16T23:45:25.843472+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]  
2020-12-16T23:45:26.287947+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]  
2020-12-16T23:45:26.287959+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] > server@1.0.0 server /app  
2020-12-16T23:45:26.287960+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] > npm start server.js  
2020-12-16T23:45:26.287960+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]  
2020-12-16T23:45:27.261503+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]  
2020-12-16T23:45:27.261511+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] > client@0.1.0 start /app/client  
2020-12-16T23:45:27.261512+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] > react-scripts start  
2020-12-16T23:45:27.261512+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]  
2020-12-16T23:45:27.287963+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]  
2020-12-16T23:45:27.287965+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] > server@1.0.0 start /app  
2020-12-16T23:45:27.287966+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] > node server.js "server.js"  
2020-12-16T23:45:27.287966+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]  
2020-12-16T23:45:29.329961+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] Server has started on port 5000  
2020-12-16T23:45:29.377253+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up  
2020-12-16T23:45:31.082924+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=my-bug-tracker.herokuapp.com request_id=d77f6dfd-b5e2-4f8c-b5ec-6c8ca90063dd fwd="107.181.184.23" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=62ms status=200 bytes=2573 protocol=https  
2020-12-16T23:45:31.327977+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.627d6695.chunk.js" host=my-bug-tracker.herokuapp.com request_id=3e09e810-ba9b-4ffc-80ec-1452b4dc3fde fwd="107.181.184.23" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=200 bytes=118886 protocol=https  
2020-12-16T23:45:31.580398+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/2.e6f51e71.chunk.css" host=my-bug-tracker.herokuapp.com request_id=fd127936-041d-4621-8417-4ab61d3be700 fwd="107.181.184.23" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=30948 protocol=https  
2020-12-16T23:45:31.766225+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.baebc1a0.chunk.css" host=my-bug-tracker.herokuapp.com request_id=0cbed062-cc5a-4b0b-a5b5-9e0c6c126411 fwd="107.181.184.23" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=33ms status=200 bytes=51828 protocol=https  
2020-12-16T23:45:31.800991+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/2.86007984.chunk.js" host=my-bug-tracker.herokuapp.com request_id=4cb8b8f0-7a9f-4d19-b5e7-886956ff367b fwd="107.181.184.23" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=17ms status=200 bytes=256970 protocol=https  
2020-12-16T23:45:32.395277+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/media/BlueBackground_1920.f1fd53eb.jpg" host=my-bug-tracker.herokuapp.com request_id=fec9221a-2535-4a31-aa23-faae29fd9278 fwd="107.181.184.23" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=79ms status=200 bytes=193680 protocol=https  
2020-12-16T23:45:32.435799+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/bug-icon-white-background-thick.ico" host=my-bug-tracker.herokuapp.com request_id=2c3fcb80-9d59-4e2d-82cb-e40e069572fc fwd="107.181.184.23" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=11ms status=200 bytes=14451 protocol=https  
2020-12-16T23:45:34.651092+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] Something is already running on port 32518.  
2020-12-16T23:45:34.713739+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm run client exited with code 0  
2020-12-16T23:45:38.231748+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/account/login" host=my-bug-tracker.herokuapp.com request_id=a98b5798-90c0-43d5-951e-9eedb3caf308 fwd="107.181.184.23" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=365ms status=200 bytes=18030 protocol=https  
2020-12-16T23:45:38.468324+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/media/sort-arrows-both-empty.4823f7dd.svg" host=my-bug-tracker.herokuapp.com request_id=5ac2ebe3-eade-4929-ac13-a9c130ee49ba fwd="107.181.184.23" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=9ms status=200 bytes=2668 protocol=https  
2020-12-16T23:45:38.469210+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/media/sort-arrows-top-filled.d4ef80d2.svg" host=my-bug-tracker.herokuapp.com request_id=86e2dc2d-3cbd-49f3-9bff-d0318bfd88e6 fwd="107.181.184.23" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=10ms status=200 bytes=2700 protocol=https  
2020-12-16T23:45:38.508359+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/media/fontawesome-webfont.af7ae505.woff2" host=my-bug-tracker.herokuapp.com request_id=1c3618aa-6c2d-4849-9742-40b7cf76c25e fwd="107.181.184.23" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=10ms status=200 bytes=77438 protocol=https  
2020-12-16T23:46:24.944613+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=my-bug-tracker.herokuapp.com request_id=0825b13a-7917-43d4-bcd9-c0c96df2dc06 fwd="107.181.184.23" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=237 protocol=https  
2020-12-16T23:46:25.177238+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/2.e6f51e71.chunk.css" host=my-bug-tracker.herokuapp.com request_id=24c6a746-e906-49db-83ce-ccbe39a274ab fwd="107.181.184.23" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=30948 protocol=https  
2020-12-16T23:46:25.179901+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.baebc1a0.chunk.css" host=my-bug-tracker.herokuapp.com request_id=d88baeaf-45ac-44fa-8e36-8b4a513c0e9f fwd="107.181.184.23" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=51828 protocol=https  
2020-12-16T23:46:25.184930+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/2.86007984.chunk.js" host=my-bug-tracker.herokuapp.com request_id=23923f21-2b35-4eae-9ec4-a5bb511f7fc9 fwd="107.181.184.23" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https  
2020-12-16T23:46:25.674846+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.627d6695.chunk.js" host=my-bug-tracker.herokuapp.com request_id=92de810a-64b1-4723-ade4-f3af20f16914 fwd="107.181.184.23" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https  
2020-12-16T23:46:25.895205+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/media/BlueBackground_1920.f1fd53eb.jpg" host=my-bug-tracker.herokuapp.com request_id=8120bdf0-664b-42a5-9466-47ff254605e0 fwd="107.181.184.23" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=14ms status=200 bytes=193680 protocol=https  
2020-12-16T23:46:26.005483+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/bug-icon-white-background-thick.ico" host=my-bug-tracker.herokuapp.com request_id=6d37a9df-6bad-44c6-bf4c-4871036094b0 fwd="107.181.184.23" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=14451 protocol=https  
2020-12-17T00:17:57.035580+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling  
2020-12-17T00:17:57.038063+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down  
2020-12-17T00:17:58.600226+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM  
2020-12-17T00:17:58.725162+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143  
2020-12-19T00:16:45.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user myemail@outlook.com  
2020-12-19T00:18:36.760218+00:00 app[api]: Release v32 created by user myemail@outlook.com  
2020-12-19T00:18:36.760218+00:00 app[api]: Deploy a56a8d74 by user myemail@outlook.com  
2020-12-19T00:18:37.085799+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting  
2020-12-19T00:18:38.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded  
2020-12-19T00:18:46.854143+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm run dev`  
2020-12-19T00:18:49.111701+00:00 app[web.1]:  
2020-12-19T00:18:49.111720+00:00 app[web.1]: > server@1.0.0 dev /app  
2020-12-19T00:18:49.111721+00:00 app[web.1]: > concurrently "npm run server" "npm run client"  
2020-12-19T00:18:49.111721+00:00 app[web.1]:   
2020-12-19T00:18:50.371711+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]  
2020-12-19T00:18:50.371740+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] > server@1.0.0 server /app  
2020-12-19T00:18:50.371741+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] > npm start server.js  
2020-12-19T00:18:50.371741+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]  
2020-12-19T00:18:50.685530+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]  
2020-12-19T00:18:50.685542+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] > server@1.0.0 client /app  
2020-12-19T00:18:50.685542+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] > npm start --prefix ./client  
2020-12-19T00:18:50.685543+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]  
2020-12-19T00:18:50.962753+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]  
2020-12-19T00:18:50.962763+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] > server@1.0.0 start /app  
2020-12-19T00:18:50.962764+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] > node server.js "server.js"  
2020-12-19T00:18:50.962764+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]  
2020-12-19T00:18:51.591232+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up  
2020-12-19T00:18:52.237451+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]  
2020-12-19T00:18:52.237462+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] > client@0.1.0 start /app/client  
2020-12-19T00:18:52.237463+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] > react-scripts start  
2020-12-19T00:18:52.237464+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]  
2020-12-19T00:18:54.475128+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] Something is already running on port 36160.  
2020-12-19T00:18:54.500055+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm run client exited with code 0  
2020-12-19T00:21:30.162248+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/" host=my-bug-tracker.herokuapp.com request_id=d2dde696-e905-4999-b060-8f55e67638f8 fwd="73.133.94.85" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=8ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https  
2020-12-19T00:23:04.490925+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting  
2020-12-19T00:23:04.507527+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting  
2020-12-19T00:23:05.356455+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM  
2020-12-19T00:23:05.438828+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143  
2020-12-19T00:23:17.170024+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm run dev`  
2020-12-19T00:23:20.333801+00:00 app[web.1]:  
2020-12-19T00:23:20.333826+00:00 app[web.1]: > server@1.0.0 dev /app  
2020-12-19T00:23:20.333827+00:00 app[web.1]: > concurrently "npm run server" "npm run client"  
2020-12-19T00:23:20.333827+00:00 app[web.1]:  
2020-12-19T00:23:21.436851+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]  
2020-12-19T00:23:21.436873+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] > server@1.0.0 server /app  
2020-12-19T00:23:21.436873+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] > npm start server.js  
2020-12-19T00:23:21.436874+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]   
2020-12-19T00:23:21.498752+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]  
2020-12-19T00:23:21.498754+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] > server@1.0.0 client /app  
2020-12-19T00:23:21.498754+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] > npm start --prefix ./client  
2020-12-19T00:23:21.498755+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]  
2020-12-19T00:23:22.064333+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]  
2020-12-19T00:23:22.064355+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] > client@0.1.0 start /app/client  
2020-12-19T00:23:22.064356+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] > react-scripts start  
2020-12-19T00:23:22.064356+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]  
2020-12-19T00:23:22.116724+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]  
2020-12-19T00:23:22.116727+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] > server@1.0.0 start /app  
2020-12-19T00:23:22.116729+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] > node server.js "server.js"  
2020-12-19T00:23:22.116729+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]  
2020-12-19T00:23:23.302719+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up  
2020-12-19T00:23:24.037351+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/" host=my-bug-tracker.herokuapp.com request_id=6c715c5a-4f70-4e16-8a4c-307adb441f0a fwd="73.133.94.85" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https  
2020-12-19T00:23:24.579638+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] Something is already running on port 9268.    
2020-12-19T00:23:24.631826+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm run client exited with code 0
```

Comment: Can ya pass us your entire repo so we can have a closer look?

Comment: @HenryLy here ya go -- https://github.com/CodyTheCoderPrice/Bug-Tracker